# How can I bulk rename a bunch of files moving a portion of the name to another spot

Tags: terminal, macos

I have a bunch of files of the form:
"1.1 Recursive Sequences KEY.pdf"

I'd like to change that to be:
"1.1 KEY Recursive Sequences.pdf"

I have rename installed to my terminal, but I'm not sure how to make this work.

I tried this: `rename -n '*\ *KEY*'; '$1\ KEY\ $2$3'`

But, it didn't work, I thought this would break up the filename into:
$1 - everything before the first space
$2 - everything between the space and "KEY"
$3 - everything after "KEY"

Then I would reassemble in the proper order.  I clearly don't understand what I'm doing.  Please help!

Actual file names:

```
0 Algebra 1 Refresh KEY.pdf
0 Algebra 1 Refresh WS.pdf
0 River Crossing Day 1 Challenge.pdf
1.1 Recursive Sequences KEY.pdf
1.1 Recursive Sequences Lesson.pdf
1.1 Recursive Sequences Student.pdf
1.2 Applications of Arithmetic Sequences KEY.pdf
1.2 Applications of Arithmetic Sequences Lesson.pdf
1.2 Applications of Arithmetic Sequences Student.pdf
1.3 Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence KEY.pdf
1.3 Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence Lesson Intro Vid.webloc
1.3 Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence Lesson Solution Vid.webloc
1.3 Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence Lesson.pdf
1.3 Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence Student.pdf
1.4 Applications of Geometric Sequences KEY.pdf
1.4 Applications of Geometric Sequences Lesson.pdf
1.4 Applications of Geometric Sequences Student.pdf
1.4b Sum of a Geometric Series KEY.pdf
1.4b Sum of a Geometric Series.docx
1.4b Sum of a Geometric Series.pdf
1.4b1 Lesson Math Medic.pdf
1.4b1 Review 1.1 to 1.4 - Algebra 2 - Math Medic.docx
1.4b1 Review 1.1 to 1.4 - Student.pdf
1.5 Linear Relationships KEY.pdf
1.5 Linear Relationships Lesson.pdf
1.5 Linear Relationships Student.pdf
1.6 Point-Slope Form of a Line KEY.pdf
1.6 Point-Slope Form of a Line Lesson.pdf
1.6 Point-Slope Form of a Line Student.pdf
1.7 Standard Form of a Linear Equation KEY.pdf
1.7 Standard Form of a Linear Equation Lesson.pdf
1.7 Standard Form of a Linear Equation Student.pdf
```

Basically, I want to bring the final word into the second position.  Though 'Student' will become 'WS'.

Comment: Can you please add a few actual file names and how the result should like like for each? It is doable, but heavily depends on the real file names.

Comment: That is one of the exact names.  Basically the form of the names is: "#.# words KEY.pdf". I've added a list of files from this folder.

Comment: So you want to turn „1.1 Recursive Sequences Lesson.pdf“ into „1.1 Lesson Recursive Sequences.pdf“ and „1.4b Sum of a Geometric Series.pdf“ into „1.4b Series Sum of a Geometric.pdf“?

Comment: Technically, no, I don't want to change every one of the files.  But most files do need to be changed.  If the last word is "Lesson", "KEY", or "Student" I want to move the word to the front.  Ideally I would change "Lesson" to "LP" when moving it and "Student" to "WS" but those changes are simple to do in a second step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different `rename` versions out there, so it's hard to guess what kind of regexps are supported in the version you installed. But assuming that the filename mentioned in the question represents the structure of all those you want to convert, the following should work:

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    t=$(sed -E 's/([^ ]*) (.*) (.*)\.(.*)/\1 \3 \2.\4/' <<< "$f")
    echo mv "$f" "$t"
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you verified that it works as expected.

---

This uses the substitution command in `sed` to modify the filename.

```
s/([^ ]*) (.*) (.*)\.(.*)/\1 \3 \2.\4/
```

The part between the first set of `/` is used to match the existing name:

- `[^ ]*` matches all leading non-space characters (the chapter number in your case)
- The space matches the space
- `.*` then matches all characters up to the last space character in the name
- The space again matches the space
- `.*` matches everything from the last space to the `.`
- The last `.*` matches the suffix (technically everything after the `.`)

The `()` are used to mark the matched parts, they are referenced from the second part of the substitution command (`\1 \3 \2.\4`) to rebuild the name in the form required.

Comment: This worked great!  But can you explain what is happening?

Comment: @DannyWhittaker see edit

Answer (score -1):

May be a GUI-tool with a graphical user interface could be of help. I have no personal experience with this one, but it showed up when searching: https://www.transnomino.com